# Copying sub unit of an old schematic to a new project in Proteus

Tags: proteus

I copied an old schematic to a new project in proteus but when I tried creating the corresponding PCB design on ARES, the components/parts section didnt show any of the components used in the schematic diag. And when I again tried looking up those parts in the library and placing them on the ARES working area it Displayed a message "components cannot be placed because the design is locked"
IN short PCB design is not mapping the schematic design.

Comment: Which version of Proteus were you using? You may have to paste it in, save it, exit the program, load it back up, then try transferring to ARES

Comment: You may also have to try right clicking a few components, then 'edit properties' and make sure it has a model type, and PCB package with it

Comment: You get "design is locked" if you don't synchronize

Comment: I am using Proteus 8. The problem is if I am trying to make the schema from scratch in a new project then all the components used for the schematic is being shown in the components list of the Ares work space and and it is able to map the schematic. buts thats not the case when i just copy paste n save it.

Comment: @DirkBruere I am actually still new to this .. I dont exactly know what you are trying to refer by synchronize here

Comment: @Manali At the bottom of the Ares screen there is a sync box/symbol that you need to click to transfer changes between Ares and Isis